# How to get React Native APP running on Android Emulator to reach local api

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I am running a React Native app that was configured using Android Studio on Windows 10. This app runs in an emulator. Normally I use a combo of `npm start` and `npm run android:dev` in 2 separate terminals to start the app.

I have an asp.net api as well that is running on http://localhost:5000 on my computer.
My computer's local IP is `192.168.0.84`.

My react native app does not/cannot seem to reach my API at all.
I ran fiddler to capture Http/Https traffic locally and I never see a network request.
Though I can see google maps requests come in from the emulator when I go to the settings screen.

I have tried setting my react native app's API URL to `http://localhost:5000`, this does not work and gets a rejected promise when network requests are made.

I have tried setting my react native app's API URL to `http://192.168.084:5000` this also does not work but no errors are generated.

API urls for other environments such as dev or qa that use FQDN work as expected.

What specifically do I need to do to get this working locally?
Are there specific proxy settings on the emulator I need to configure on this screen?
[image: android emulation proxy settings]

Are there port forwarding settings I need to do with ADB?

Comment: To access localhost on Android you should use the ip `10.0.2.2`. So it should be `http://10.0.2.2:5000` on fetch or axios.

Comment: @ErickMaeda, that seems to be what it needs to be to work. Please type up an answer and I will accept it.